# Marketing Cloud Landing Page: pass values to a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I created a landing page which auto-populates first name, last name and the email. Now I need to pass these 3 along with what radio buttons are selected by the user to a data extension other than the sent one.

I guess is something to do with the submit button for the radio buttons form but how? I have to tell somehow which data extension and what fields/values to add but I don't know how.

Is there any easy way to do that?

Thanks, VD

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set up a microsite page that handles the form submission and does something with the values. AMPscript has a function `RequestParameter()` that gets values from an HTTP Post. You take these values and insert them into your DE.

## A Really Simple Example

Here is the simplest example I can think of to do what you need. You will have 2 microsite pages: **Form**, which contains the actual HTML form, and **Handle Form** which handles the HTTP Post and inserts the values into your DE.

**Form**

```
<html>
    <form id="myForm" method="post" action="/url/to/handle/form">
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="Jon" />
        <input type="radio" name="beer" value="lager" />Lager<br />
        <input type="radio" name="beer" value="ipa" />IPA
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</html>
```

*Note: you need to replace the form's `action` attribute with the URL to your **Handle Form** page*

**Handle Form**

```
%%[ 
    set @beer = RequestParameter("beer")
    set @firstname = RequestParameter("firstname")
    InsertData("Some Data Extension","beer",@beer,"firstname",@firstname,"Date",Now())
]%%

%%=v(@beer)=%%
<br />
%%=v(@firstname)=%%
```

The above example will work, but it's not great because it does not contain any validation and requires the user to navigate back if there is an issue. ExactTarget has some documentation on validating forms which can be read here: **[Using AMPscript to Validate Fields in a Landing Page](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/landing_pages/using_ampscript_to_validate_fields_in_a_landing_page/)**

## A More Advanced Example

This example might be beyond the scope of your question but I want to share it as it might help someone down the road. As someone who's done this more than few times in SFMC I prefer to use ajax to submit and handle the form. The **Handle Form** page is requested using JavaScript and has a content type of `application/json`. You would select JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) from the Content Type dropdown when creating your page.

The content of your Handle Form page would look something like the code below. It looks for the required values and if they are present it inserts into the DE and returns success as true. Otherwise it returns false allowing you to handle the error appropriately on the front end. Using JavaScript to handle the form in this way will allow you to to provide a better user experience for whoever is using your site.

```
%%[
    set @success = true
    set @beer = RequestParameter("beer")
    set @firstname = RequestParameter("firstname")

    if Empty(@beer) or Empty(@firstname) then
        set @success = false
    else 
        InsertData("Some Data Extension","beer",@beer,"firstname",@firstname,"Date",Now())
    endif

]%%
{
  "success" : "%%=v(@success)=%%"
}
```

Comment: This is really useful Jon, thanks for such a detailed answer, I will give this a try and let you know how it goes!

Comment: I receive an error - I checked the data extension and the field names are identical as per my script: "The Data Extension field name for a InsertData function call is invalid. A field of this name does not exist."

Comment: Can you post the de fields and your insert data function in a comment?

Comment: I have problems pasting the code here because of the multiple @ so I had to use jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gvwcej1v/

Comment: Either remove `"Date",Now()` from the InsertDE function, or add a Date field called Date to your Registered DE.

Comment: nice, now I have pushed the 2 radio buttons values but is not saving the name and the email... 
The first name and last name are auto-populating on the landing page like this <input type="text" name="FirstNameLastName" value="%%First_Name%% %%Last_Name%%" /> <input type="text" name="Email" value="%%Email%%" /> do I do something wrong?

Comment: actually I tested from within ET, let me send an email test and I will check from there...

Comment: nope, the first and last name and the email are not auto-populating and they are not saved to the data extension for some reason. I will try to use hidded fields are per your example and separate them in separate fields, First Name, Last Name and Email instead of having both first and last name called in one field and see how that goes.

Comment: You need to pass those values to the landing page somehow. You should use the personalization string `microsite_base_url` and then you can call them the same way you do in an email.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29414/discussion-between-jon-sakas-and-dinovici).

Answer (score 1):

when creating the AJAX request I had to use a GET rather than a POST so the "RequestParameter" would pick it up