# Get values of chekbox to use them on AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have created a landing page, i have a form in my page :

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="demoForm" id="demoForm">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Preference du client : </legend>

    <p><input type="checkbox" name="pref1" id="pref1" value="1" /> Je souhaite me desabonner des communications mails </p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="pref2" id="pref2" value="2" onclick="show()"/> Les communications mails ne sont pas adaptees, je souhaite mettre a jour mon centre de preferences </p>

    <div id="active_sub" style="display:none" >
        <p><span>Etes-vous interesse par des communications sur les themes :</span>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="cycling" value="cycling" /> cycling</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="running" value="running" /> running</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="visit gym" value="visit gym" /> Gym</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="swimming" value="swimming" /> swimming</label>
    </div>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

I'm trying to get the values of from the chekbox and display them using **APMScript**, i've tried this :

```
%%[ 
    set @var = RequestParameter("cycling")
    set @var2 = RequestParameter("running")
]%%

%%=v(@var)=%%
%%=v(@var2)=%%
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestion ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to replace the form's action `attribute` with the URL to your landing page

```
<form action="LandingPageURL" method="post" class="demoForm" id="demoForm">
```

Refer the related post: [Marketing Cloud Landing Page: pass values to a data extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93183/marketing-cloud-landing-page-pass-values-to-a-data-extension)

Comment: it works thank you.