# Looking for Cloudpage ID personalization string

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, cloudpage, smart-capture

Is there any personalization string to retrieve cloud page ID  within the same cloud page as i am using the smart capture form on it i have cloud page id as a hidden field. I am adding it to the data extension so we can track consent and versions of the Cloud page.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a parameter on the URL then you could use ampscript `RequestParameter()` function.

See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/146831/45908.

If you want the full URL then you could get it with JavaScript : `window.location.href`

Comment: Ya i tried it sorry i should have mentioned that when i used %%_EmailID%% getting blank or zero.

Comment: Does it have to be the cloud page of? Or could you not log the URL instead?

Comment: I can live with URL too how can i retrieve the url? eventually my goal is to send back this info to sales cloud